# Apply a ValueConverter to a TextBlock in a style

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, styling

I'm trying to ensure all `TextBlock` elements with style `HeadingL4` end up in all caps, ideally without any explicit reference to the value converter required to do the job in any of the `TextBlock`s themselves (after all, it's entirely possible the business will decide to use small caps or underlining or bold for headings at some point in the future).

I thought I was onto something with a style

```
<Style TargetType="TextBlock" x:Key="HeadingL4" BasedOn="{StaticResource CustomBase}">
    <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource AllCapsConverter}}" />
</Style>
```

However, whilst this results in conversion taking place, the value in the TextBlock doesn't update, which means presumably the conversion is either happening too late or too early; either conversion is taking in the style and then then `Text={Binding MyHeading}` gets applied (with local property values overriding style values), or - correctly - `MyHeading` is applied, followed by the style (that takes the `MyHeading` value and converts it to an all caps version), but for whatever reason the view never updates with the new value (possibly because as far as it is concerned the value is the same?).

Can anyone tell me how to correctly inject a Converter for the `Text` property of `TextBlock` elements via a style?

I should add, it's entirely possible this is obvious stuff - I'm a relative newbie to WPF, and even more so to styling.

Comment: There is nothing like a "converter for the Text property", the converter is instead a property of the binding.

Comment: So is there a way to access the binding and modify it? Does that mean that the issue I'm facing is I'm generating a second binding, but not replacing the first one (because the target of the style's setter is `Text` not `Text.Binding.Converter` (where the syntax here is obviously wrong, but the semantics should be clear)?

Comment: With setting `Text={Binding MyHeading}` you are actually replacing the binding from the Style Setter, which makes the Setter useless.

Comment: I wondered about that... yet the goal is to apply a style to the arbitrarily bound value of a TextBlock. Obviously (to me at least) this makes sense to bind in the element rather than the style (I may not know what the name of the property I want to bind is for all `HeaderL4` styled `TextBlock` elements throughout the app - I just know that I want them all to be all caps). So the question becomes: How do I leave the binding in the hands of the original element, but style it so it comes out all caps based on the style, rather than a converter applied when the binding is declared?